# memcached installation on LAMP issue

Tags: lamp, memcached, php

When trying to use memcached in my php script, i get class not found. I am running LAMP on Ubuntu 9.01 and have so far taken the following few steps:

```
apt-get install memcached
pecl install Memcache
apache2ctl restart
```

I see the memcache extension when viewing phpinfo, but no memcached?!

Is there anything else that i need to do to be able to use memcached in my script? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Search for "memcache class not found" at Google yields [Memcache Class Not Found](http://lists.danga.com/pipermail/memcached/2007-August/005010.html) thread with troubleshooting instructions:

Run `php -i | grep memcache` to ensure that PHP was compiled with the `--enable-memcache` option.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install php5-memcache
```

another 3 minute hold... la la la la la la.... two robot checks... la la la la..... and another robot check.. whee....